# How to add cards in a cardview(recyclerview) with different colours for each card according to the user's selection?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I am making an app which uses recyclerview, database and cardview to show the elements. I want to add a feature which allows the user to select the colour of each card they add. For instance, there red or green. Since I am just a beginner I do not know how to implement this feature. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add below code in `onBindViewHolder` method

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.itemView.getBackgroundTintList().equals(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED))){
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                }else {
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
                }
            }
        });
```

this code change the color of each cardView by clicking.